# Solidify only cup's bottom and handle?

Tags: 3d-printing

I can't really use the Solidify modifier because I don't want to mess with the entire object. The goal is to print a cup but enforce the handle and the bottom of it. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: just change its geometry, maybe show a screenshot of your object

Comment: You can use solidify in edit mode too. Not the modifier. Just select the geometry what you want to add thickness then hit space (or the find button) and type in solidify.